# Groovy - unexpected MOP methods in the class node for com

Tags: eclipse, groovy, mop

No idea what this is coming from.
Using groovy eclipse plugin v2.61, groovy compiler 1.8.6, eclipse 3.7

I could include some code here, but the error is generate in the middle of the comment header

```
/**
*
*  <--   somewhere here
*
*/
```

Tried clean project, rebuild project and related tricks

Question: What is MOP, and is there a way to disable it ?

Francis

PS.  Switching to groovy compiler 1.7 makes the error go away, but that's hardly a solution (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

I get this error frequently and what I have to do is

1. Empty the class causing error or all the code (no code just open close paren for the class)
2. Save the class and the error goes away
3. Ctrl-Z to get all the code in the class back
4. Save the class and the error does not come back

Strange but true. Got this solution after spending a lot of time on trial and error to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an internal groovy compiler error that is being interpreted as a user error.  Without more information, there's not much I can say.  The best thing you can do is attach a code snippet here and I will try it out.  If you can't attach a snippet here, go to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE and raise an inssue there.  Please attach a failing project that I can use to recreate.

Comment: ok - will try to cook something up.  I showed already a code section (the comments) but that's indeed hard to analyse :-)